# GCM Network Manager não executa as tarefas

Tags: android

Olá! Senhores tenho duas tarefas e noto que as mesmas não estão sendo executadas, eu chamei as mesmas na atividade principal no onCreate() contudo se eu for para outra atividade as tarefas não são chamadas, qdo volto e espero o tempo determinado há a execução, outro detalhe é que das duas tarefas uma só executa apenas uma vez
Uma tarefa faz um GET e recebe um json é uma tarefa rápida já a outra ela obtém dados do banco e faz um POST, estou usando a lib loopj para a network.

```
    gnm = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);

    PeriodicTask task1 = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(AtualizacaoService.class)
            .setPeriod(50)
            .setFlex(10)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setTag("atualizacao")
            .build();

    PeriodicTask task2 = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(EnviarService.class)
            .setPeriod(80)
            .setFlex(10)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setTag("envio")
            .build();

    gnm.schedule(task1);
    gnm.schedule(task2);
```

Um dos serviços

```
public class AtualizacaoService extends GcmTaskService {
   private static final String TAG = "AtualizacaoService";

   private CustomSharedPreference shared ;
   private OrdemServicoService service ;
   private SincronismoService sincronismoService;
   private Sincronizacao sinc;
   private Date ultimaAtualizacao;
   private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
   private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

   @Override
   public void onInitializeTasks() {
       super.onInitializeTasks();
       Log.i(TAG, "onInitializeTasks()");
   }

   @Override
   public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
       Log.i(TAG, "onRunTask()");
       retrieverUpdateFromRemoteServer();

       return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
   }

   public void retrieverUpdateFromRemoteServer(){

    service = new OrdemServicoService(getApplicationContext());
    sincronismoService = new SincronismoService(getApplicationContext());
    User user = ((Aplicacao) getApplicationContext()).getLoginUser();

    params.put("data", sdf.format(this.ultimaAtualizacao)  );
    params.put(Helper.TOKEN, user.getToken());
    params.put(Helper.SERVIDOR, "1");

    CustomRequest serverRequest = new CustomRequest(
            Helper.PATH_TO_SERVER_ATUALIZACAO ,
            this.params,
            createRequestSuccessListener(),
            createRequestErrorListener());

    serverRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            Helper.MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(serverRequest);
}
```

Comment: Qual a versão do android que você está utilizando. O GCM tem alguns problemas com versões do android. Recomendo trocar pelo [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) da evernote, nunca tive problemas.

Comment: Olá meu caro, boa tarde, olha eu tinha tido um problema anterior e por isto eu fiz uma "gambi" depois percebi que era a causa da segunda task não estar executando na verdade ela estava sim mais uma unica vez, removi e deu tudo certo, eu sei que o meu Smart é bronca o Android é o 4.4 mais agora ta de boa valeu.